# Symfony coding standards - arguments and parameters

Tags: symfony, coding-style

In the [Symfony coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html) it says:
>

> Use camelCase, not underscores, for variable, function and method names, arguments;
>
> Use underscores for option names and parameter names;

In this context, **what is the difference between parameters and arguments**?

I think I understand the option names part (i.e. when you have an $options array, like in the code example on that page) but what qualifies as a 'parameter'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that when **array values are used as options** (have the meaning of), in general.

For example in forms:

```php
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'validation_groups' => array('registration')
    );
}
```

In your bundle configuration:

```php
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme_hello');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->scalarNode('my_type')->defaultValue('bar')->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

In container parameters:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    my_mailer.class:      Acme\HelloBundle\Mailer
    my_mailer.transport:  sendmail

services:
    my_mailer:
        class:        "%my_mailer.class%"
        arguments:    ["%my_mailer.transport%"]
```

Comment: Ah... so the config.yml (or other .yml file) settings are parameters. Thank you!

Comment: @caponica yes, basically `config.yml` files are used for bundle configuration (assetic, security and even your own). Usually you define parameters (along with their values) in `parameters.yml` and use that parameters with the `%...%` notation in your config files.